# Download a file with AFHTTPSessionManager and with authentication

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm working on an iOS app using OAuth2 authentication.

I'm authenticated, I have no problem requesting my API, but I'm facing a problem when trying to download some files from protected URLS.

I'm using `downloadTaskWithRequest` from `AFURLSessionManager` (AFNetworking). It returns always an error 401 (not authorized) as if I was not logged in.

I can access this URL with no problem if I use the GET method, but I would like to use `downloadTaskWithRequest` because it permits me to have a progress indicator.

Here's my code (which isn't working):

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [apiC downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
     NSURL *dstPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dstFilePath];
    return dstPath;

} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

    // HERE I HAVE A 401
}];
```

Here's my code that *does* work:

```
[[OEOApiClient sharedClient] GET:url parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    // SUCCEDD !!
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Does `downloadTaskWithRequest` not support authentication? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I was creating my request the wrong way :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

this was the good way :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [mySessionManager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:url parameters:nil error:&serializationError];
```

Comment: how to get full path where file is saved

Answer (score 0):

The `request` you're creating and passing to `downloadTaskWithRequest:…` is different from the one generated by your request serializer in `GET:parameters:…`.

Look at the implementation of `GET:parameters:…` to learn how AFNetworking generates requests using request serializers. Then use the same code to make an authenticated request object to pass to `downloadTaskWithRequest:…`.